# Python solve complex inventory in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, inventory-management

Need your help on solving ordering inventory. This is only 4 items, however the real DataFrame has 10,000 items.

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

```
    Inventory count Batch size  Store A needs   Store B needs   Store C needs    Total requires:    Actually requires: 
Buckets         198      20             63               18             104           185                   220
Candy Bars      876     100            567              435             673          1675                  1800
Coke (cans)    1759       6           1212              758             836          2806                  2814
Masks (boxes)  2000    1000            333              444             555          1332                  3000
```

- df['Inventory count'] is how much inventory I have on hand
- df['Batch size'] is how much I have to assign in multiples each time

The buckets row I have 198 buckets on hand. The 3 stores total required is 185, however due to batch size, 63->80, 18->20, 104->120, 80+20+120 = 220. How do I assign the inventory?

Candy Bars and Coke both inventory count is less than the df['Actually requires:'], how can I assign them based on demand ranking?

Alternatively, I am open to suggestions if there are better solutions

this is the dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPLC.jpg)

Please I need your assistance, and thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll qualify this response by saying you should search allocation strategies for inventory and/or supply chain management if the above example is oversimplified - meaning many more stores and/or inventory allocation strategies needed.

I'm just returning a dictionary, but if you want or need to, you can write the data back to columns in the dataframe or create a new dataframe or send the data off to a file directly. All depends on what you need to do.

```
import math

def allocation(x):
    max_units_available = math.floor(x['Inventory count'] / x['Batch size'])
    sa_units_need = math.ceil(x['Store A needs'] / x['Batch size'])
    sb_units_need = math.ceil(x['Store B needs'] / x['Batch size'])
    sc_units_need = math.ceil(x['Store C needs'] / x['Batch size'])

    allocation_needs = [sa_units_need, sb_units_need, sc_units_need]
    # print(allocation_needs)
    # print(max_units_available, tota_untis_need)
    if max_units_available >= sum(allocation_needs):
        return dict(zip(store_list, allocation_needs))
    else:
        #allocation goes in order until all units are allocated
        #you can pass as many allocations strategies as you wish, you just need to code them
        #and work them into your code
        store_list = ['Store A received', 'Store B received', 'Store C received']
        allocation_received = [0]*len(allocation_needs)
        inv_sum = 0

        for i in range(0, len(allocation_needs)):
            inv_sum = inv_sum + allocation_needs[i]
            if max_units_available < inv_sum:
                allocation_received[i] = max_units_available
                break
            else:
                allocation_received[i] = allocation_needs[i]
            max_units_available = max_units_available - allocation_needs[i]
        # print(dict(zip(store_list, allocation_received)))
        return dict(zip(store_list, allocation_received))
    
    df.apply(lambda x: allocation(x), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Buckets            {'Store A received': 4, 'Store B received': 1, 'Store C received': 4}
CandyBars          {'Store A received': 6, 'Store B received': 2, 'Store C received': 0}
Coke(cans)      {'Store A received': 202, 'Store B received': 91, 'Store C received': 0}
Masks(boxes)       {'Store A received': 1, 'Store B received': 1, 'Store C received': 0}
```